# How to rotate sprite and move

Tags: android, logic, sprite, andengine, move

How do I move sprite of sprite's front direction. I've andengine gles 2. I tried add sprite and I gave speed but sprite just left, top, bottom and right I wanna sprite can cross direction. i.e. when I rotate sprite's front, move that direction. How can move that just where the front my sprite ? So, if sprite's front look at the bottom sprite gotta move bottom direction, and if sprite front direction of the upper left sprite gotta move upper left. Like this image..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/muoSg.png

My code...

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
        float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {

        //Rotate left button
        if(id==0){ 

       shipSprite.setRotation(-10);}
```

//Speed button

```
        if(id==1){
  shipSprite.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-400);
```

}

```
    return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
}
```

not going to cross(i.e. sprite's front)... just going Y direction..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the code you have tried, pointing out where your issues are. "write me the code" questions are very likely to be closed

Comment: Firstly thanks for reply, i added my code. I hope someone can help me :/ @MarioTrucco

Comment: Hi, you there is nothing like front of sprite in andEngine. Buto you can calculate this like shown in the answer from user2413972. Also you should not rotate sprite alone when using box2d physics. Rotate body instead, sprite will follow rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know andengine. And did not find anything on **"andengine move sprite forward"**. But I can offer mathematical meaning:

[image]

a - your rotation.
Do not forget to normalize the vector. Good luck!

```
shipSprite.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(f.x);
shipSprite.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(f.y);
```